On a certain Fibonacci identity
I'm examining the expression involving the Fibonacci numbers
$$-231F_{2n+1}^3+264F_{2n+1}^2F_{2n}+198F_{2n+1}F_{2n}^2-33F_{2n}^3-308F_{2n+1}^2+308F_{2n+1}F_{2n}+308F_{2n}^2+231F_{2n+1}-33F_{2n}+321.$$
It seems that this evaluates to 0 somewhat frequently, albeit not for the first several values. Is it true that this evaluates to 0 infinitely often?

Here is a computer assisted proof that the expression is always equal to $13$. Each step can be checked manually as well. Consider the polynomials
$$P_k(X,Y):=\frac{X^k-Y^k}{\sqrt{5}}.$$
Note that
$$F_k=P_k(x,y),\qquad\text{where}\qquad x:=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad y:=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$
Now consider also the polynomials
$$Q_n(X,Y):=-231P_{2n+1}^3+264P_{2n+1}^2P_{2n}+198P_{2n+1}P_{2n}^2-33P_{2n}^3-308P_{2n+1}^2+308P_{2n+1}P_{2n}+308P_{2n}^2+231P_{2n+1}-33P_{2n}+321.$$
Mathematica tells us that
$$25 Q_n(X,Y)=11 \left(Y^{4 n} \left(-3 \sqrt{5} X^{2 n} (X (Y (21 Y-16)-6)-4 Y (2 Y+3)+3)-140 ((Y-1) Y-1)\right)+15 \sqrt{5} (7 X-1) X^{2 n}-140 ((X-1) X-1) X^{4 n}-3 \sqrt{5} (7 X-1) ((X-1) X-1) X^{6 n}+Y^{2 n} \left(140 X^{2 n} (X (2 Y-1)-Y-2)+3 \sqrt{5} X^{4 n} \left(X^2 (21 Y-8)-4 X (4 Y+3)-6 Y+3\right)-105 \sqrt{5} Y\right)+3 \sqrt{5} (7 Y-1) ((Y-1) Y-1) Y^{6 n}\right)+165 \sqrt{5} Y^{2 n}+8025.$$
Plugging $(x,y)$ into $(X,Y)$, Mathematica tells us that the expression becomes
$$25 Q_n(x,y)=325.$$
Hence $Q_n(x,y)=325/25=13$, which means that the original expression equals $13$.
Here is a quick Mathematica code to verify that the original expression is constant $13$:
x := (1 + Sqrt[5])/2
y := (1 - Sqrt[5])/2
f[k_] := (x^k - y^k)/Sqrt[5]
FullSimplify[-231 f[2 n + 1]^3 + 264 f[2 n + 1]^2 f[2 n] + 198 f[2 n + 1] f[2 n]^2 - 33 f[2 n]^3 - 308 f[2 n + 1]^2 + 308 f[2 n + 1] f[2 n] + 308 f[2 n]^2 + 231 f[2 n + 1] - 33 f[2 n] + 321, Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]]


Well it would seem the code I wrote to evaluate this was throwing quite some errors!
